Is there a way to get rid of the horizontal stroke in visx AreaClosed?
I use visx. My data starts late but I don't like the vertical stroke on the start. It is an AreaClosed and currently the stroke is stroke={"rgba(255,255,255,1)"}. I want to get rid of the vertical stroke on the start. My target is below. Is there a way to do that?
current
my target
I put a stroke with stroke={"rgba(255,255,255,1)"} but it put stroke on every side.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
